# Calling Java Script function from JSP page not returning value

Tags: javascript, jsp

I have written a java script function which will return Language name based on code passed to the function as argument.

I am getting code from the servlet as response. I tried in the following way:

```
----
</fieldset>
    <fieldset class = "field">
        <legend>Language</legend>
        <table border = '0'>
            <tr>
                <td>Spoken:</td>
                <!-- <td><input type = "text" name = "FirstName"  value = "${spoken}"/></td> -->
                <td><input type = "text" name = "spoken"  value = getLanguage(${spoken}) /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>Written:</td>
                <td><input type = "text" name = "written"  value = "${written}"/></td>
            </tr>
        </table>

</fieldset>
----
```

Java script function:

```
<script>
function getLanguage(code) {
    if(code.equals("EN"))
        return "ENGLISH";
    else if(code.equals("SP"))
        return "SPANISH";
    else
        return "";
}
</script>
```

But in output instead of displaying language I am getting function call displayed. Can someone tell me what is happening wrong here?

Comment: may be JS function will call only some events ....

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can't do like this. You will be passing code to js function and then inside a js function you can dom manipulation. Like that;

```
<script>
function setLanguage(code, elementId) {
    if(code.equals("EN"))
        document.getElementsByTagId(elementId).val = "ENGLISH";
    else if(code.equals("SP"))
        document.getElementsByTagId(elementId).val = "SPANISH";
    else
        document.getElementsByTagId(elementId).val = "Unknow";
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to place calls to javascript function between `<script>` and `</script>`.

There could be several ways of solving this. One solution is as follows:

In your html, use

```
<input type = "text" name = "FirstName"  data-value = "${spoken}"/>
```

Note how `data-value` attribute holds the value of `spoken`.

Then have the following `<script>` block *after* `getLanguage()` is defined:

```
<script>

(function() {
  var input = document.querySelector('input[name=FirstName]')[0];
  var code = input.getAttribute('data-value');
  input.setAttribute('value', getLanguage(code));

})();

</script>
```